# PDB Folder being created at root of drive when running in debug

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure-web-roles

I inherited an Azure ASP.NET web role project from another developer. When I run it in debug in Visual Studio 2012, it runs fine, but dozens of .pdb folders are created at the root of the drive the solution and project files are. I do not get this with any of my projects.

It also seems to take an inordinate amount of time to start-up, which may also be related.

Can someone point me to the potential configuration option that has been messed with that has stopped these folders being created in the default locations (which I assume should be in the /bin/debug area?).

Comment: I'm having this same issue with one of my projects. @NER1808 did you have any success figuring out what was going on? Thanks!

Comment: No sorry. I gave up on that one!